# Django class based views

Tags: python, django

url pattern

```
 url(r'(?P<username>\w+)/$', ProfileView.as_view()),
```

view

```
class ProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProfileView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

My main view function makes sure logged in users are redirected to their profile page, thus:

```
WEBSITE/users/someuser
```

Will call to my ProfileView.as_view(), However this still permits users to alter the url to something like:

```
WEBSITE/users/someotheruser
```

Which isn't harmfull because it will still just render the request.user data, but I would rather catch this behaviour by always redirecting to the current user.. I don't really understand how?

Comment: Why is username part of the URL, if it's completely ignored anyway? Change the pattern, problem solved.

Comment: You're absolutely right.. thinking too complicated :-) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class ProfileView(TemplateView):
template_name = "home.html"

    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.username == username:
            return super(ProfileView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```